# ELK : Change format of the field thanks to filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

In the logs I upload to Kibana have a "mytimestamp" field, supposedly of type Date but when I inject the logs and parsed it in json, my timestamp is converted to type string.

Do you know how can I convert my timestamp field from String to Date thanks to Filebeat ?

I must necessarily use Logstash ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like you have an issue. Field can be timestamp in Kibana, but when you fetch results with REST API from elasticsearch you will get timestamps as strings because JSON itself doesn't have timestamp format defined, so it's up to the application that is parsing it to decide what is date and parse it properly. None of the tools for log ingestion is going to help you in this case.

Comment: So I have to change the format of the log file and use Logstash for parsing ?

Comment: I'm not sure how your environment looks like, but it seems you have application in the end parsing JSON after fetching data from elasticsearch. If it is so, you need to parse the date yourself. You can maybe avoid that with some kind of library for elastic queries.